# OnRestoreInstanceState got a problem in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

Am working on an alarm app, and my layout happens to contain a TimePicker View used to set the time the user wishes to be reminded of something. I seem to have a problem with the methods applied in saving values when the Activity is being sent to the background. The code in the compiler is clean with no errors and yet when I debug it on smartphone, I send the Application to the background and then when resume it the TimePicker current hour is not modified by these two methods...Your time and contributions are well appreciated

`````
 class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
      TimePicker timePicker2;
       int x=2;
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //Timepicker definition
         timepicker1=this.FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.timepicker1);
          //Setting the default selected time of the Timepicker via OnCreate
        timepicker1.CurrentHour=Java.Lang.Integer.ValueOf(x);

        }
     //This method supposedly overrides another method called OnSavedInstanceState and allows programmer to save values to it
      protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            int y;
            y = 2;
         //Saving my value to Bundle savedInstanceState
            savedInstanceState.PutInt("value",y);
           //This super is being called but i dont know what it does
            base.OnSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
     //This method is supposed to remember all the values user saved before the Activity went into OnPause()
//Changed this from public to protected because i figured onsavedInstanceState has its parameters protected so unless its an inheritance, access to its members is forbidden
        protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            //Restore the time value from the SavedInstance state
            int c = savedInstanceState.GetInt("value");
           //Assign the value to The Timepicker
            timePicker2.CurrentHour=(Java.Lang.Integer.ValueOf(c));
        }
}````
What am i doing wrong? An additional alert dialog code to detect when activity goes into Onpause and OnRestore will greatly be appreciated
`````

Comment: Hi, when back to foreground of the app, you could have a try with recreate the activity to check wehther the `TimePicker` show the current hour.

Comment: I tried that didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I seem to have a problem with the methods applied in saving values when the Activity is being sent to the background.

You could have a check with this **[Activity.OnRestoreInstanceState Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.onrestoreinstancestate?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)** to know:

> This method is called after `OnStart()` when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in `savedInstanceState`.

[image]

This method will not be called when you back from background, it only be called after being re-initialized. Such as `Recreate()` method will invoke it.

Therefore, here when entering to background, the `OnSaveInstanceState` method works. However, `OnRestoreInstanceState` will not be called.

Now if you want to sotre some data and restore view between background and foreground, you could use `SharedPreferences` in `OnResume()` and `OnPause()` of **Activity**.

For example, code as follows:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int value = prefs.GetInt("value", 0);
    timePicker1.CurrentHour = (Java.Lang.Integer.ValueOf(value));
}


protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();
    ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
    int y;
    y = 2;
    editor.PutInt("value", y);
    editor.Apply();
}
```

Then the effect will show:

[image]